# How can a delegated portal admin assign permission sets to other portal users?

Tags: community, permission-sets

How can a delegated community administrator assign permission sets to other portal users ? I read somewhere that it requires 'Manage External Users' System Permission but I don't see that permission on a community user profile.

We have a community plus license and are implementing communities in our salesforce org. We have assigned some community users as delegated admins. The issue is that when I login as the delegated admin I don't see the option of assigning permission sets (unlike when I am logged in as system admin and can assign permission sets to any user)

Comment: Please clarify your question. First, what kind of community license do you have in your org? Next, are you asking if a community user can be given delegated admin permssions to assign permission-sets to other community users??

Comment: The community license we are using is 'Customer Portal Manager Custom'. The requirement I have is to delegate administration to a some portals users  and they need to assign permission sets to other portal users.  Delegating them as admin is not the problem but I want to know if they can add permission sets to the portal users. Appreciate any ideas you have on this. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't your community license type! Do you have a customer community, a partner community, community plus, or a HVCP license for your community? You're referring to a profile or permission set, not a community license type! Please visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Actually we do have a community plus license and are implementing communities in our salesforce org and we have assigned some community users as delegated admins. The only issue is that when I login as the delegated admin I don't see  the option of assigning permission sets (unlike when I am logged in as system admin and can assign permission sets to any user).

Comment: I have edited your post and nominated it to be reopened. Once open again, I believe I can answer it for you.

Comment: @crmprogdev: I have achieved the solution using a custom visualforce page to assign the permission sets to the users programmatically. Thanks for your responses and considering my question.